# Google Admob api create too much threads

Tags: android, admob

I'm having an weird problem with google admob api for android.... I dont know exactly how and when but it start creating too many threads and end up by crashing the whole system.
I got this error in production and still not able to reproduce it in dev

this is the stack:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
   at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
   at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1339)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ac.execute(ac.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.activeview.b.a(b.java:5)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.j.a(j.java:30)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ad.a(ad.java:4)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ae.run(ae.java:2)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at aam.a(aam.java)
   at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.e.a(e.java:1)
   at aam.dispatchMessage(aam.java)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

this stack doesn't say too much is just generic but if i take a print screen of my crashlytics dashboard:

[image]

and this goes over and over and over if i scroll down according to crashlytics there are 1024 threads at this moment

does anyone know why it is happening

is use:   `api("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1")`

this problem happens in around 5% of the sessions IN PRODUCTION what is around 1000 times PER DAY

i wasn't able to reproduce in dev. but i didn't change anything in my code or updated the app in weeks
==============update==================

i'm 100% sure this was a google's issue (as it always is), i did absolutelly NO CHANGE and the crashed decreased 90%

google never admit their mistakes but it happened at same time that firebase stopped accouting my admob revenue (out of nowhere) and the same came back without my intervention

[image]

Comment: post your code to let us know how you are going to load ads.

Comment: Please post some of your code which you are using for loading the ads.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this? I have thousands of same crashes for more than a week so far.  I wonder if downgrading play-services-ads might help.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also having this issue and looking at the logs it dates back to the beginning of June. There's a Google groups thread with a lot of people complaining about it here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/cbr_oV4Yzfg

It looks like something the Admob team have broken.